# Forecast the total energy consumption of country

Tags: statistics

We have conducted a survey of 4,000 households across the entire country, with samples taken from few city in several states. For instance, in a few cities within a state, we have a sample size of 30. Now, with only the city populations as the known factors, I want to estimate the overall consumption for these cities from this sample.How can I do that? After city I want to forecast this for whole country

How can I get data of entire population with just sample size of 30 household.

Comment: Can you add an example of the data that you have?

Comment: yes, Suppose i have columns city, state, climate, number of appliances, category of city, Age of buildings number of rooms, total number of persons living in a household, Source of income, income level, education level.

Answer (score 0):

In order to infer on the real population based on this sample I think you might need something more than the columns provided in your comment. However, having only this available I would start to search for descriptive statistics (for the city/region that you want to infer to) of certain feature that you showed here.

Assuming certain features to be normally distributed you can perform some simple hypothesis testing on those features.

Example: Test that the mean income level of your sample is the same as the one of the city of interest:

- H_0: mean_sample = mean_city
- H_1: mean_sample =/= mean_city

Here you have a snippet:

```
from scipy import stats

sample_data = [...]  # Your sample data
mean_city =  # Mean of the city

# HP testing
t_statistic, p_value = stats.ttest_1samp(sample_data, mean_city)

# Output results
print("T-Statistic:", t_statistic)
print("P-Value:", p_value)

# Results
alpha = 0.05  # Set acceptance value (no more than 0.1)
if p_value < alpha:
    print("Reject null hypothesis: The mean of the sample is significantly different.")
else:
    print("Fail to reject null hypothesis: There is not enough evidence to suggest that the mean of the sample is different.")
```

Recall that these kind of tests relies on the assumption that data do follow a normal distribution, so this might also be tested. If they don't other types of distribution may be took to perform the test.

Comment: but my target variable here is energy consumption. How can I relate this? Also can I use CLT here?

Comment: My idea was first to see if the sample can be said statistically homogenous with respect to the entire population of the respective city or region, based on several features like: income,  number of persons living in a household, age of buildings, isolation efficiency and so on (of course the more the better).

Then, once you are confident about the representativeness of your sample, you can model the electricity consumption with simple time series model, like `ARIMA` in order to forecast the national consumption.

Comment: Can you explain me in details that how can i identify that if the sample is statistically homogenous? what can i do if it is homogenous or not?

Comment: You can use the method showed in the answer itself. Let me make and example:

You have a sample of householders in New York City, and you want to test if the income of the households of your sample is the same as the one of the entire city, you can test it with the code I've provided, having both the mean income of the sample and of the entire city.

Recall that if you've found my contribution useful, an upvote would be appreciated :)